# ng-snotify service 9.0.1 with angular 13.3.11

Tags: angular

I have updated angular to the latest version, and I have problem with snotify service, it's not compatible with angular 13.3.11, does anyone have idea how to fix it

the error shows next

npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@9.1.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^9.0.0" from ng-snotify@9.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/ng-snotify
npm ERR!     ng-snotify@"^9.0.1" from the root project

Here is my package.json file,    *

```
{
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "node ./src/scripts/header.js && ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~13.3.11",
        "@angular/common": "~13.3.11",
        "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.11",
        "@angular/core": "~13.3.11",
        "@angular/forms": "~13.3.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.11",
        "@angular/router": "~13.3.11",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.2",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.1.2",
        "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.32",
        "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
        "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "chalk": "^4.1.2",
        "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "js-base64": "^3.6.1",
        "ng-snotify": "^9.0.1",
        "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
        "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
        "ngx-print": "^1.2.1",
        "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
        "sass": "^1.51.0",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.7",
        "@angular/cli": "^13.3.7",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.11",
        "@angular/language-service": "~13.3.11",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~6.0.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "^6.3.20",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~4.6.4"
      }
    }
```

- 

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: There is no version with official support for a recent Angular version, see https://github.com/artemsky/ng-snotify/issues/115. The error occurs during npm install. You can try adding an [`override`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) for `@angular/core` to your `package.json`, or run  `npm install --force`, to force Angular v13. But that doesn't necessarily mean that your project is able to build and run, it's just a way to get the install to work.

Comment: After updating, I got this error for routerLink, I have added RouterModule to app-routing.module and app.module, does have something that I don't know?  "Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'div'."

Comment: Well your initial question seems to be answered... If you have another question please ask a new question.

Comment: I would like, but app doesn't allow me...